# JS: Problemas com a ordem de um array de Dates

Tags: javascript, data, fs

Olá!

Estou tendo problemas no **Javascript** com a ordem de um array. Basicamente, eu pego uma lista de objetos e ordeno ela segundo um de seus atributos que é um `Date`. Porém, quando dou um `console.log`, quando uso em uma função ou quando coloco em um .txt, **aparecem resultados diferentes e o array fica parcialmente ordenado.**

Especificando:

1 - Eu ordeno o array da seguinte forma:

```
commands.sort(compareDate)

function compareDate (command1, command2) {
  if (command1.date.getTime() < command2.date.getTime()) {
    return -1
  }
  if (command1.date.getTime() > command2.date.getTime()) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}
```

Depois, se eu printo ele por `console.log`, tudo parece ordenado (atenção nos horários):

```
[ { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:50.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEUP' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:51.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEUP' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:52.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEDOWN' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:54.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEUP' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:56.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEDOWN' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:57.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEDOWN' },
  { date: 2019-06-02T16:26:59.000Z, button: 'NET_VOLUMEUP' },
...
```

Depois, eu quis colocar tudo em um .txt, então fiz:

```
for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
  write(commands[i].date + ',' + commands[i].button)
}

function write (text) {
  fs.appendFile('logs/parsed.txt', text + '\r\n', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err)
    }
  })
}
```

O que me gera um resultado já fora de ordem (atenção nos horários e ignorar o fuso):

```
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:52 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:51 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:54 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:57 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:56 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:59 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:01 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:01 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:02 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:03 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEDOWN
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:27:03 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 13:26:50 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),NET_VOLUMEUP
Sun Jun 02 2019 15:39:24 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),SAM_CENTER
Sun Jun 02 2019 15:38:12 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),SAM_POWER
Sun Jun 02 2019 15:38:12 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00),SAM_POWER
```

Tentei usar também `date.toString()`, `date.toUTCString()` e `date.toLocaleString()`, o que também gerou resultados fora de ordem. Pior que isso, **os resultados não parecem seguir um padrão.** Ora o segundo objeto que está fora de ordem, ora o terceiro objeto, e assim vai.

Cogitei o fato de que isso poderia ser problema da função `fs.appendFile`, mas o problema é que **quando eu percorro esse array em uma outra função e consumo os objetos dele, eles também aparecem com alguns índices fora de ordem**, prejudicando o funcionamento do meu código.

Alguma ideia? Alguma ajuda?

Comment: A função `appendFile` é assíncrona, se você chamar ela novamente antes dela terminar de escrever, como você está fazendo no `for`, é possível que o seu array será escrito fora de ordem mesmo. Por que não envia seu texto de uma vez ao invés de chamar o io várias vezes?

Comment: Perfeito! 
Imaginei que poderia ser algo em relação à funções assíncronas, mas não tinha pensado numa solução tão simples quanto chamar o appendFile já com o texto todo montado.  
Obrigado!

Comment: Podes musar este jsFiddle até reproduzires o problema? https://jsfiddle.net/pkzxyf1a/